# How to count number of times guard statement happens in recursion?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell and I got stuck in a little program I tried to make. I want to count number of times my guard statement goes through in all recursion rounds and then return that as Int. For example if `c1` is `'a'`, `c2` is `'b'`, `g` is `2` and `s` is `"aaabbb"` then returned int would be 2, because my guard statement is true in 2 cases.

I tried to make variable `x` and then add `x + 1` to it every time guard statement happens. That didn't work because I learnt that in Haskell variable you set is always static so for example setting `x = 0` at start would set that `x` to 0 every recursion round.

Here's my code:

```
gaps :: (Char, Char) -> Int -> String -> Int
gaps (c1,c2) g (s:xs)
   | c1 == s && c2 == (s:xs) !! g = --Count how many times this statement happens --
   | otherwise =  gaps (c1,c2) g xs
```

Comment: Since that is the "base" case of the recursion, it will always be done once.

Comment: Maybe I asked it bit wrong but my real question is not how many times it happens in single round but how many times in total this statement goes through. For example if c1 is a, c2 is b, g is 2 and string is "aaabbb" it should return 2 because that statement happens twice.

Comment: well then I guess you should use a `State` monad (or `StateT`, etc.) and update the number of calls accordingly.

Comment: @Willem-Van-Onsem No, that is needlessly complicated for a simple problem like this.

Comment: @Hjulle: well based on the comment, I had the idea that it should count the total amount of evaluates where `gaps` can be called multiple times. The idea of `State` is then to at least hide the complexity of the state that will be "implicitly" passed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `1` and call the function recursively

```
gaps :: (Char, Char) -> Int -> String -> Int
gaps _ _ [] = 0                                           -- base case 
gaps (c1,c2) g (s:xs)
   | c1 == s && c2 == (s:xs) !! g = 1 + gaps (c1,c2) g xs -- add one to final result
   | otherwise =  gaps (c1,c2) g xs

> gaps ('a','b') 2 "aaabbb"
2
> gaps ('a','b') 3 "aaaabbbb"
3
```

Be carefull when using  `!!`. It isn't total and might fail if your input string has `c1`'s values less than `g` positions before the end of the string

```
> gaps ('a','b') 3 "aaaababbb" -- doesn't fail
3
> gaps ('a','b') 3 "aaaabbabb" -- does fail!!!!
```

Comment: Do you have suggestion about what to use instead of `!!` to be safer?

Comment: @Hjulle: use something like [`atMay :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.17/docs/Safe.html#v:atMay) or [`(!!!)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ShellCheck-0.7.0/docs/ShellCheck-AnalyzerLib.html#v:-33--33--33-).

Comment: @Hjulle use william's answer. I've also seen the `!?` operator, but I can't remember if it was define only for vectors or any for index-like data structures.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually really close to answer but I didn't realise to call function recursively in that other statement as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

Off the back of questions on how to make this thing safer, I have made the following code snippet, borrowing from Ismor's answer.

```
-- a way to safely get the nth item from a list
get' :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
get' [] _ = Nothing
get' (x:xs) 0 = Just x
get' (x:xs) n 
 | n > 0 = get' xs (n-1)
 | otherwise = Nothing

-- takes a Maybe value. if it's Nothing, return 0. if it's Just a value, compare
-- the value and a given param, if equal return 1, else 0
seeEqual:: (Num b, Eq a) => Maybe a -> a -> b
seeEqual Nothing _ = 0
seeEqual (Just a) b
 | a==b = 1
 | otherwise = 0

-- I have edited the first guard so that it checks c1 and s, then tries to calculate
-- whether c2 and the specific list item are equal, and then recurses as before
gaps :: (Char, Char) -> Int -> String -> Int 
gaps _ _ [] = 0 -- base case 
gaps (c1,c2) g (s:xs) 
 | c1 == s = (seeEqual (get' (s:xs) g) c2) + gaps (c1,c2) g xs -- add one to final result 
 | otherwise = gaps (c1,c2) g xs
```

I do not claim that this is perfect, but I do think this is safe and shouldn't throw any exceptions or raise any errors.

```hs
Prelude> gaps ('a','b') 3 "aaaababbb"
3
Prelude> gaps ('a','b') 3 "aaaabbabb"
2
```